# Google Chome extension - Jquery isn't working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I currently developing a google chrome extension and my jquery isn't working there's no error in the console or what it just doesn't work in my `address.js`. I want in my chrome extension is to get the value of the textbox in my browser and post it in my extension

**This is my Webpage Code**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<label for="field">Address</label>
<input id="field" type="text" style="width: 200px;">
        <input type='button' id='alertButton' value='click me'>


</body>
</html>
```

**This is my popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src = "address.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>

    <input id="innpu" type="text" style="width: 200px;" >


  </body>
</html>
```

**and my address.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#alertButton').click(function(){
      $("#innpu").val("testing123");
    });

    $('#dds').click(function(){
      $("#field").val("testing123");
    });
})
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)  (and perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery will not work on the browser page.
You should write an other javascript file called as content script and mention it manifest.json.
Content script works with the DOM elements of your browser page.
It is a pure javascript file.
Don't add it to your extension's html page.